# How to update a txt file on java

Tags: java, javafx, file-io, text-files

I have a text file and I want to update **everytime only the last 3 labels**

The changes will be made via ID (1,2 etc.)

**p.g.** (for ID=1  **change:** 10,18/10/18,7 to 12,21/10/18,2)

User.txt:

```
1,alex,pass,Admin,Alexandros,Karatzas,Male,18/10/1990,A'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952301,10,18/10/18,7
2,maria,pass1,User,Maria,Karatza,Female,18/10/1990,B'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952381,20,18/10/18,5
```

So after run i want to take this as output:

```
1,alex,pass,Admin,Alexandros,Karatzas,Male,18/10/1990,A'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952301,12,21/10/18,2
2,maria,pass1,User,Maria,Karatza,Female,18/10/1990,B'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952381,20,18/10/18,5
```

The code searches for ID, reads-writes data but how can i replace the last 3 labels everytime?

Source Code:

```
    @FXML 
         TextField ID3,abs,Dabs,Fabs
    @FXML
    public void UseAddAbs() throws IOException {                //Kanei Add tis Apousies sinfona me to ID
        String searchText = ID3.getText();
        Path p = Paths.get("src", "inware", "users.txt");
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(p.getParent(), "usersTemp", ".txt");
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
                BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile)) {
            String line;

            // copy everything until the id is found
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                writer.write(line);
                if (line.contains(searchText)) {
                    writer.write("," + Fabs.getText());
                    writer.write("," + Dabs.getText());
                    writer.write("," + abs.getText());
                    break;
                }
                writer.newLine();
            }

            // copy remaining lines
            if (line != null) {
                writer.newLine();
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    writer.write(line);
                    writer.newLine();
                }
            }
        }

        // copy new file & delete temporary file
        Files.copy(tempFile, p, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.delete(tempFile);
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried so far, and what doesn't work? so far, you've just copied your assignment here, that isn't a very constructive way to ask to improve what you have

Comment: i make it on javafx to read write on file via ui

Comment: i paste my code

Comment: Code: thanks to Fabian. so go and ask Fabian, if you are just posting his code anyway.

Comment: but on this version of code just go to end of the line and paste the new labels but i want to replace the last 3 labels (10,18/10/18,7 to 12,21/10/18,2)

Comment: im noobie.... i found it on internet and work on another place i used it but now i want to **replace the last 3 label** .

Comment: what is a **label** to you?

Comment: 10,         18/10/18,         7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the lines and work on fields:

```
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] fields = line.split("[,]");
            if (fields[0].equals(searchID)) {
                fields[12] = "12";
                fields[13] = "21/10/18";
                fields[14] = "2";
            }
            writer.println(String.join(",", fields));
        }
```

Update: my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String searchText = "1";
        Path p = Paths.get(".", "users.txt");
        Path tempFile = Files.createTempFile(p.getParent(), "usersTemp", ".txt");
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(p);
                BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(tempFile)) {
            String line;

            // copy everything until the id is found
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] fields = line.split("[,]");
                if (searchText.equals(fields[0])) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; ++i) {
                        System.out.println(i + ": " + fields[i]);
                    }
                    fields[12] = "12";
                    fields[13] = "21/10/18";
                    fields[14] = "2";
                }
                writer.write(String.join(",", fields));
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }

        // copy new file & delete temporary file
        Files.copy(tempFile, p, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        Files.delete(tempFile);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have try the solution. but it delete all the file content

Comment: @FoticPap no, it doesn't

Comment: dont know, but is not working for me, can complete the solution? Thanks

Comment: @FoticPap here you go

Answer (score 0):

You can split line into array and update last 3 array elements. 
Then all you have to do is build new line from that array and write this line instead of an old one.

Example:.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.contains(searchText)) {
        String updatedLine = updateLastNStrings(line, 3);
        writer.write(updatedLine);
        break;
    } else {
        writer.write(line);
    }
    writer.newLine();
}

private String updateLastNStrings(String line, int n) {
    String [] parts = line.split(",");
    for (int i = parts.length - n; i < parts.length; i++) {
        // update String
        String newPart = parts[i] + "_UPDATED";
        parts[i] = newPart;
    }
    return String.join(",", parts);
}
```

**Input:**

```
1,alex,pass,Admin,Alexandros,Karatzas,Male,18/10/1990,A'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952301,10,18/10/18,7
2,maria,pass1,User,Maria,Karatza,Female,18/10/1990,B'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952381,20,18/10/18,5
```

**Result**

```
1,alex,pass,Admin,Alexandros,Karatzas,Male,18/10/1990,A'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952301,12_UPDATED,21/10/18_UPDATED,2_UPDATED
2,maria,pass1,User,Maria,Karatza,Female,18/10/1990,B'Likeiou,Antreas,Karatzas,6945952381,20,18/10/18,5
```

Note updated String with `_UPDATED`

**Note**

Besides all that, the code you found is flawed, since to find ID it is searching if line contains a charSequence. What if ID is a content of a line?

Example:

```
1,some_content,2,3
2,some_content,1
```

You try to find a line by id `2` and first line will be updated instead of a second one.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i didnt notice that, i will chage the IDs to 1000+

Comment: I try the solution it works, but it throws IO.Exception and is not replace the the users file just create a usersTemp with the changes

Comment: What does the exception say? You might want to close buffers before copying new file `writer.close(); reader.close();`

Comment: I see it closely, create a temp file with the old data + _Update. The massage is so long i cant even post it :P

Comment: What do you mean you see it closely? You don't have to copy whole stacktrace....copy message and first few lines.